# Static method inaccessible from a derived class

Tags: c++

How do I make a static method inaccessible from a derived class?

I have an inheritance of classes of the following type Square
from which rectangle and rhombus are derived. Then from the rectangle and rhombus a parallelogram is derived. Then from the parallelogram the trapezoid is derived.

I read all these objects (square, rectangle, rhombus, parallelogram, trapeze) in an object vector, but in the end I want to show how many of each I have read. I want to do this through static functions for each class.

Here is the code:

```cpp
class A
{
protected:
    static int n;
public:
    A();
    static void numberA()
    {
        cout << n;
    }
};

int A::n;

A::A(){ n++; }

class B:public A
{

protected:
    static int n;
public:
    B();
    static void numberB()
    {
        cout << n;
    }
};

int B::n;
B::B(){ n++; }

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    A::numberA();
    cout << endl;
    B::numberB();

    return 0;
}
```

output:
2
1

And I want 1, 1 because it is one object of class A and one of class B.

I also tried to make the inheritance private or protected but for nothing.

Comment: Why don't you indent your code?

Comment: Any class constructor will implicitly call the parameterless constructor of its base. So `B b;` calls both the constructor of A and B.

Comment: Put some code like `cout << "Hello constructor A\n"` and  `cout << "Hello constructor B\n"` in your constructors and you'll understand

Comment: Your model seems strange. A rectangle is not a square, and neither is a rhombus. A parallellogram is not both a rectangle and a rhombus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the constructor of the derived class will call the base class constructor too.

An easy fix could be to decrement the count of the base class in the derived constructor.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
protected:
    inline static int n_{};  // Since C++17
public:
    A()
    {
        ++n_;
    };
    static int number()
    {
        return n_;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
protected:
    inline static int n_{};
public:
    B()
    {
        ++n_;
        --A::n_;              // Decrease base count 
    }
    static int number()
    {
        return n_;
    }
};

class C : public B
{
protected:
    inline static int n_{};
public:
    C()
    {
        ++n_;
        --B::n_;              // Decrease base count 
    }
    static int number()
    {
        return n_;
    }
};

class D : public A
{
protected:
    inline static int n_{};
public:
    D()
    {
        ++n_;
        --A::n_;              // Decrease base count 
    }
    static int number()
    {
        return n_;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    D d;
    std::cout << A::number() << '\n' << B::number() << '\n'
              << C::number() << '\n' << D::number() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```